# Capturar, em página PHP, o valor de um input que foi alterado em tempo de execução

Tags: php, javascript

O JS abaixo captura o valor da URL e atribui ao `value` do `input`.

```
var valor_num = /num_nfe=([^&]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];

//console.debug("Num. NFe: "+$("[name='num-nfe']").val());
//console.debug("Form: "+ JSON.stringify($('#meu_form').serializeObject()));

$.post("actions/autosalvar.php", function (data) {
            $("[name='cliente']").attr('value', data.cliente);
            $("[name='id-cliente']").attr('value', data.id_cliente);
            $("[name='tipo-pessoa']").attr('value', data.tipo_pessoa);
            $("[name='num-nfe']").attr('value', valor_num);
}, "json");

setInterval(function () {     
                var dados = $('#meu_form').serializeObject();
                $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", 
                {'meus_dados': dados}).done(function( data ){});
}, 2000);
```

Contudo, inicialmente, ao tentar capturar esse valor na página `autosalvar.php` o mesmo não está definido, ficando disponível somente numa segunda execução.

**1º execução da página `autosalvar.php`**

```
Array
(
    [cliente] => João
    [id-cliente] => 2
    [tipo-pessoa] => PF
)
```

**2ª execução [após o intervalo de 2 segundos] da página `autosalvar.php`**

```
Array
(
    [cliente] => João
    [id-cliente] => 2
    [tipo-pessoa] => PF
    [num-nfe] => 59
)
```

Comment: Você está executando o script pela primeira vez antes de carregar completamente a pagina?

Comment: Sim, o script está no `header.php`. @WagnerSoares

Comment: O primeiro `post` é para recuperar os dados e preencher o formulário, correto? E a cada 2s são atualizados os dados conforme o que está no formulário. Entendi certo?

Comment: Certíssimo @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Primeiro, para ficar mais *semanticamente correto*, utilize o verbo HTTP `GET` para recuperar dados na primeira instância. `POST` apenas quando for salvar o formulário. Segundo, as duas requisições são enviadas ao arquivo `actions/autosalvar.php`, inclusive a primeira, que é apenas para recuperar os dados, sem enviar nada. Como está fazendo esta distinção?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss podemos continuar essa discussão via chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54076/sincronismo-de-dados-php-com-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A solução se deu da seguinte forma:

→ Passar como argumento o valor do `input`, na primeira requisição `$.post`:

```
var val_num = $("[name='num-nfe']").val();
$.post("actions/autosalvar.php", {'val_num': val_num}).done(function (data) {
...
}, "json");
```

→ Já no PHP receber os dados assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['val_num'])){ // 1ª instância do $.post
   $valor = $_POST['val_num'];
}else{
   $valor = &$_POST['meus_dados']['num-nfe']; // Outras instâncias
}
```